# Is "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions" configuration affects non sql shuffling?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, partitioning, shuffle

We don't have a lot of SQL in our Spark jobs (That is a problem I know but for now its a fact).
I want to optimize the size and number of our Spark shuffle partitions to optimize our Spark usage. I saw in a lot of sources that setting `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` is a good option. But will it do any effect if we almost do not use spark SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` has no effect on jobs defined through the RDD api.

The configuration you are looking for is `spark.default.parallelism`,
according to [the documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html):

> Default number of partitions in RDDs returned by transformations like join, reduceByKey, and parallelize when not set by user.